# I want to tweak this simple html javascript page of mine

Tags: javascript, html

My aim in this simple html file is to load a block of div that affiliates to someone who would like to log in. My div "loginProper" is that div I'm talking about. I've put an onClick function on my other divs which contains the name of the people who can login. My problem is nothing happens when I click those divs.

Here is the code, can you please check what is missing?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Project Design Exhibit</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showLogin(loginType){
        if (loginType=="a"){
            document.getElementById("loginProper").innerHTML = "Administrator Login";
        }else if (loginType="s"){
            document.getElementById("loginProper").innerHTML = "Student Login";
        }else if (loginType="g"){
            document.getElementById("loginProper").innerHTML = "Special Guest Login";
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div style="margin:0 auto; width:1000px; border:1px solid black;">
    <div style="width:1000px; height:50px; border:1px solid black;">
        <div style="display:inline; border:1px solid black;" onClick="showLogin(a)">Admin</div>
        <div style="display:inline; border:1px solid black;" onClick="showLogin(s)">Student</div>
        <div style="display:inline; border:1px solid black;" onClick="showLogin(g)">Special Guest</div> 
    </div>
    <div id="loginProper" style="margin:0 auto; width:500px; height:700px;"></div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. you're missing quotes when passing 'a', 's', and 'g' to your
   function
2. your javascript function is not using == when comparing
3. I also made it so your cursor turns into a 'hand' when hovering over your div ;-)

   ```
   <head>
       <title>Project Design Exhibit</title>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           function showLogin(loginType)
           {
               alert(loginType);
               if (loginType == "a")
               {
                   document.getElementById("loginProper").innerHTML = "Administrator Login";
               } else if (loginType == "s")
               {
                   document.getElementById("loginProper").innerHTML = "Student Login";
               } else if (loginType == "g")
               {
                   document.getElementById("loginProper").innerHTML = "Special Guest Login";
               }
           }
       </script>
   </head>

   <body>
       <div style="margin:0 auto; width:1000px; border:1px solid black;">
           <div style="width:1000px; height:50px; border:1px solid black;">
               <div style="display:inline; border:1px solid black;cursor: pointer" onclick="showLogin('a')">Admin</div>
               <div style="display:inline; border:1px solid black;cursor: pointer" onclick="showLogin('s')">Student</div>
               <div style="display:inline; border:1px solid black;cursor: pointer" onclick="showLogin('g')">Special Guest</div>
           </div>
           <div id="loginProper" style="margin:0 auto; width:500px; height:700px;"></div>
       </div>
   </body>

   </html>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It'd be

```
onClick="showLogin('a')";
```

and

```
loginType=="g"
```

not

```
loginType="g"
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2NyUc/)

Answer (score 0):

That's because `showLogin` function is expecting a literal/string variable...

```
function showLogin(loginType){
    if (loginType=="a") //<----THIS IS A STRING
```

Yet, you are passing in an object that doesn't exist...

```
onClick="showLogin(a)"
```

`a` is an object that can't be resolved. You should change the `onclick` handler to...

```
onClick="showLogin('a')"
```